# Spans containing line through the origin in direction of vector in the set of the span.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

span{u,v} contains the line through the origin in the direction of u.
TRUE OR FALSE?

The solution manual:
"True; the span of u is included in the span of u and v."

My answer:
FALSE. u and v could both be zero, and would not include a line.

Who is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you are technically correct. My suspicion is that the the question is making a latent assumption that $\vec u,\vec v\neq\mathbf 0$ in which case the solution manual is correct.